# Como modelar com herança uma estrutura de Pessoas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modelagem, herança, active-record

Olá, estou com dificuldades para fazer minha modelagem de Pessoa. Teoricamente parece uma coisa bem simples, porém não encontro uma maneira que siga, digamos, "das boas práticas de programação".
Meu problema é o seguinte:

Em meu sistema eu tenho uma estrutura de várias pessoas, como por exemplo: User, Client, Supplier, Employee...(entre outros).
A cima de todas essas classes pretendo ter uma classe Person onde todos os meus "atores" irão herdar. Um ator do tipo Client também pode ser um User e/ou Supplier e/ou qualquer outro ator (Afinal, é isso que acontece na vida real).

Pretendo ter apenas UMA tabela para Person, para que quando eu for associar um Client com uma venda(Sale), eu associo o ID da Person.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de ter, por exemplo, as seguintes possibilidades com meus objetos:

```
-> person = Person.new(name: "Jonn")
-> person.name #> "Jonn"
-> person.user #> nil

-> user = User.new(name: "Joe", login: "joe", password: "123456")
-> user.name #> "Joe"
-> user.login #> "joe"
-> user.person.user.login #> "joe"
```

Alguém saberia me dar uma dica de como eu poderia fazer a modelagem para as tabelas do banco de dados e a codificação para os Models?

Dês de já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, vou postar aqui mesmo qual foi a solução que encontrei e atende todas as minhas necessidades.

Primeiramente criei a gem [delegate_associations](https://github.com/Brunomm/delegate_associations) e adicionei em meu projeto.

O Passo seguinte foi ajustar minhas migrações:

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :cpf_cnpj    
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users, id: false do |t|
      t.primary_key :person_id
      t.string :login
      t.string :password
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateSellers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sellers, id: false do |t|
      t.primary_key :person_id
      t.decimal :comission, default: 0.0
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Percebam que eu removi a coluna `id` de `User` e `Seller` e adicionei como chave primária a coluna `person_id`. Fiz isso para que quando eu associar por exemplo um `Seller` para uma venda, sempre vou ter o id da `Person` que é o mesmo do `Seller`.

Depois disso criei 2 Modules:

```
# app/models/concerns/person_helper.rb
module PersonHelper
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
        validates :name, presence: true
    end
end


# app/models/concerns/is_a_person.rb
module IsAPerson
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
        include PersonHelper
        belongs_to :person, autosave: true
        delegate_associations to: :person
        delegate_attributes to: :person
        def self.find_by_id(value)
            find_by_person_id(value)
        end
        def person
            super || build_person
        end
    end    
end
```

Meus modelos ficaram da seguinte forma:

```
# app/models/person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    include PersonHelper

    has_one :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
    has_one :seller
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :seller
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include IsAPerson
    validates :login, :password, presence: true
end

# app/models/seller.rb
class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
    include IsAPerson
end
```

Agora todas as validações e metodos que uma pessoa tem eu não vou colocar diretamente no model de `Person` e sim no module `PersonHelper` para que meu `User` e meu `Seller` possam ter também as mesmas coisas.

Com isso posso ter por exemplo essas possibilidades:

```
> user = User.new(name: 'Nome da pessoa', login: 'admin', password: '123456')
> user.save # true
> user.person.persisted? # true
> user.seller #nil
> user.build_seller # Irá instanciar um Seller e associar com a Person
> user.seller.comission # 0.0

> user.name = 'Joe'
> user.person.name # Joe
```

Percebam que fica como se o `User` tivesse o atributo `name`, e toda a vez que eu seto um novo name para o `user` ele seta automaticamente na `person`. Isso acontece pelo uso da gem que eu fiz onde utilizo os artifícios do [delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate).

Talvez essa não seja a opção mais adequada, porém supriu todas as minhas necessidades e funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza relacionamentos normais 1-1 (`has_one`/`belongs_to`) ou 1-n (`has_many`/`belongs_to`) conforme o caso.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
  has_one :client
  has_one :emplyee
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  has_many :sales
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

E então crie um novo usuário dessa forma:

```
person = Person.new(name: "Joe")
person.user = User.new(login: "joe", password: "123456")
```

Se você realmente precisar criar os dois registros de uma só vez, você pode usar [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) na classe Person:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

person = Person.new(name: 'Joe', user_attributes: {login: "joe", password: "123456"})
```

Comment: desse jeito que você postou também irá funcionar, inclusive eu estava fazendo dessa maneira. Postei qual foi a solução que encontrei para suprir minha necessidade. Obrigado por responder.